# Nuxt: Is there a way to persist $auth.user?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

In my Nuxt application, when i log in, i set my user info at $auth.setUser(user) function and it stores it globally as it is supposed to, but when i refresh the page, my $auth.user object becomes a Observer object and not my user info. Is there a way to persist $auth.user so that when i refresh the page i still have my user info? I'm going to use static pages so it will be needed when my user has no connection with the server.

My login request is as follow:

```
this.$auth.loginWith('extScheme', { data: {user: this.user} }).then( ret=>{
  this.$auth.setUser(ret.data)
})
```

Thanks

Comment: cookies, localstorage

Comment: yes but is there a way so that $auth itself persist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out:

This plugin([vuex-persist](https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-persist#tips-for-nuxt)) will persist any vuex store to local storage, $auth stuff included.